# How can I create a simple grid?

Tags: acumatica

I want to create a simple gird with 2 columns, I've been trying to create it inside a new tab(Test)...

[image]

but when I add the new grid the tab disappears.

[image]

Do I need to add any more components?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab is empty because there are no visible fields in them. The framework hides empty tabs automatically.

To add fields you need to set the grid `DataMember` property first.

The value needs to be set to the name of a `DataView` contained in the `graph` bounded to the customized screen. If you need new data you need to create a `DataView` in a `graph extension`. In your scenario the `graph` used is `InventoryItemMaint`.

Example for `DataMember` property, I used `ItemSettings` DataView because it is part of `InventoryItemMaint` graph:
[image]

Then you can add the fields from the `ADD DATA FIELDS` tab:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Hugues, that's all I needed, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps that need to be followed such as adding a Data View in your graph, linking the data view to this gridetc. In case you are not familiar with this I would suggest that you follow the Acumatica T200 Training (from the Acumatica University).

Regarding Tab disappearing, I believe this might happen because your grid might not be linked correctly to the Graph. Also, Acumatica automatically removes a tab if all the components in that Tab are hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Joseph, I will consider it, have a nice day!